# J2EE Solution for implementing Proxy-Server: monitoring , tracking , saving and (reloading) Http Traffic

Tags: http, jakarta-ee, proxy, monitoring

As the title describes a Proxy should be implemented to monitor, track , save and (reloading) the Http Traffic of the outgoing requests incoming responses of client.

I am in the Design/Analysis phase: Here is the process flow:

1. Client set his request URL (the target) through a  proxy-page on the proxy (i.e: http://localhost:port_name/proxy_confg_page.html).
2. The client send a (POST/GET/etc. method) request through the proxy(at if the proxy would send it). The proxy sniffs the traffic, saving the request parameter anyhow.
3. the proxy receives the (HTTP) response from the requested URL (target URL).
4. For successful requests (Response Status code between 200-299), the proxy can save both the request and the response somehow for further processes and redirect the response to the client him to "see" its answers.
5. the client receives the incoming (http) response from the proxy and displays it.
6. the client might then click a link the response, setting it to be the next target URL for the next request, through the proxy
7. and it start all over from the beginning at step 1

i have 2 questions:

- is the process flow decribed above logical stable ? if not would'nt you mind please to correct me?
- i want to use a solid and scalable lib to process the traffic (read, update) in the proxy : i think of HttpClient. can it please do the job ? if not thank you to tell me why and which alternative might be better.

i hope to hear some good answers from some experienced Web-developers. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a Solution:
I 'll use Tomcat as forwarding proxy, by doing this.

1- in the browsers, setting the address of the web application (like http://localhost:port/Webapp)

2- in the  webapp use HttpClient to catch all the incoming request from user, save them first and then forwading then request on the outside.

3- retrieving the Response with httpClient, save the response entity and forwarding it the calling browser

Answer (score 1):

The process you described seems as an ordinary forwarding proxy excluding the first point:

> Client set his request URL (the target) through a proxy-page on the proxy (i.e: http://localhost:port_name/proxy_confg_page.html).

What do you mean by that? Does user for every single request must set request url by some administration panel? I wouldn't expect that it has any chance to success.

If you meant forwarding proxy (it's type of proxy that you set in the web browser preferences), your reasoning is fine (excluding the first point).

About your second question: HttpClient is the best tool you can use in your case - it's robust, mature and well tested library. One of the best I know.

Comment: thanks... as you said HttpClient is the best tool to be used... unfortunately i ve not yet managed the changement of version.. in the version 4.X  so many have come... someone need to learn the complete Api